# Object list from thymeleaf to spring boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass the list of product id from thymeleaf by using multiple dropdown menu. It outputs the size but the product object is null. If I create `List<String> product;` in `Expense` class and replace `expenseDetail` in `addExpense.html` with `product`; It works. I'm trying to pass product via `ExpenseDetail` class

Expense class

```
@Entity
public class Expense {
    //fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "expense", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @NotNull
    private List<ExpenseDetail> expenseDetail;
    //getters and setters
}
```

ExpenseDetail class

```
public class ExpenseDetail {
    //fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "expense_id")
    private Expense expense;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    //getters and setters
```

}

addExpense.html

```
<form th:action="@{/expense/new}" th:method="post" th:object="${expense}">
    <select id="product" th:field="*{expenseDetail[0]}">
        <option value="" th:text="#{item.select.prompt}"></option>
        <option th:each="product: ${products}" th:value="${product.id}" th:text="${product.name}"></option>
    </select>
    <select id="product" th:field="*{expenseDetail[1]}" >
        <option value="" th:text="#{item.select.prompt}"></option>
        <option th:each="product: ${products}" th:value="${product.id}" th:text="${product.name}"></option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="Save expense">Save Expense</button>

</form><!-- ends expense form -->
```

ExpenseController

```
@Controller
public class ExpenseController {
    @PostMapping("/expense/new")
    public String addExpense(@Valid Expense expense, BindingResult result, Model model){
        //This prints the list of size 2
        System.out.println(expense.getExpenseDetail().size());

        List<ExpenseDetail> el=expense.getExpenseDetail();
        el.forEach(e->{
            System.out.println(e.getProduct()); //this is null
        });
        return "addExpense";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The field on the select should be where you want the value of the selected option (product ID) to go, so you should use `th:field="*{expenseDetail[0].product.id}"`.

This will then give you a `Product` containing the selected ID within your `ExpenseDetail` objects. If nothing is chosen in the select then you will end up with a null ID in the `Product`, you'll need to handle these on the server side or use JavaScript to exclude the field if it's null.

Bear in mind Thymeleaf doesn't know anything about your `Product` object or where they come from. It will only populate the fields that appear in the form, so other things like `name` will be null in the POST handler. Typically you'd just take the ID and use it to reload the object from your DB or whatever.